# How can I add a comment to the start form of the picture library?

Tags: list, column, picture-library, settings

When selecting 'new Document' in the picture library, the window 'Add a picture' is showing up, where I can upload a picture. Is there a possibility to add a comment below as under a column like 'Please upload a picture, that is not bigger than..'

Is there a possibility, that I can add other properties/columns to the 'start page', e.g. 1. upload picture and then 2. title,.. similar to adding a new item to a list.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the easy steps to add the text below uplaod dialog of Picture Library.

1. Get the **Page URL** (like this `http://SiteColURL/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={GUID of document library}`) of the Dialog of Picture Library upload document.

**below is the image of upload page of shared document library but you will get the same for picture library**

[image]

2. Open the URL in **SharePoint Designer**.
3. Edit the page in **Advance Mode**.
4. Add the **text/comment** below to your control in **design mode**.
5. Save the dialog page.

**Note:-** It is a common page for every Library so it will change for all in SharePoint environment.

Comment: Did you achieved it? Kindly let me know if you have any problem in this. Thanks.:)

Comment: Thank you for your help!
As I am new to sharepoint I am not sure where to add the text/comment. Shall I open the Upload.aspx file and write the comment somewhere in the source code? What is Advance Mode/design mode?

Comment: You can change the code as well as design by disabling Advance mode but make sure to checkout the file first & cope the entire content to some notepad as a backup (as you mentioned that you are new). than you can make changes.

Comment: Kindly let me know if you need more help in it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know a good link to a description on how to change the source code as I am not that sure where to edit it? 
Is it possible for a beginner to adjust the forms that sharepoint creates without InfoPath?

Comment: Its an easy thing to achieve using my above given steps. Just go to design view just like Visual Studio page & add the text above the form. That's it..

Comment: I guess that was my problem: http://blog.visualsp.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-data-view-web-part-list-view-web-part-design-view-is-gone/